# For each row, get column names where data is equal to a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) with 7 rows and 4 columns (named c1, c2, c3, c4):

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
Yes No  Yes No    
Yes Yes No  No    
No  Yes No  No    
Yes No  No  No    
Yes No  Yes No    
Yes No  No  No    
No  No  Yes No
```

I want to add a 5th column to the data frame named Expected Result if the values on columns 1 to 4 are equal to "Yes". For example, on row 1, I have "Yes" parameters in Column 1 and Column 3. To populate Expected Result column, I would concatenate and add Column1 name and Column 2 name to the result.

Here is the full results expected:

```
c1, c3    
c1, c2    
c2    
c1    
c1, c3    
c1    
c3
```

I have the following line of code but something is not quite right:

```
df$Expected_Result <- colnames(df)[apply(df,1,which(LETTERS="Unfit"))]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rownum:=1:.N,]
df$Expected_result <- melt(df, "rownum")[, 
                         toString(variable[value=="Yes"]), rownum]$V1
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the comment. We can't get rid of the `No`s with `na.omit`, can we?

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I played with the data before and forgot to reload, disregard that last comment. Did something like `is.na(df) <- df == "No"` and forgot about it.

Comment: You can create a variable using `setDT(df, keep.rownames=TRUE)[]`

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: @akrun, why did you delete your answer. OP asks for your solution.

Comment: I undeleted it.  I was thinking that your solution may be better

Comment: I tried to benchmark the approach.  On a 5000*5000 dataset, your approach vs mine is 1.00 vs 1.096 (min) and 1.00 vs 1.0887 (max) in microbenchmark.  So the `base R` is not bad ...

Answer (score 6):

We can loop (`apply`) through the rows (`MARGIN=1`) of the logical matrix (`df=='Yes'`), convert to 'numeric' index (`which`), get the `names` and `paste` it together with a wrapper `toString` which is `paste(., collapse=', ')`.  We may also need a `if/else` logical condition to check if there are `any` 'Yes' values in a row.  If not, it should return `NA`.

```
df$Expected_Result <- apply(df=='Yes', 1, function(x) {
                       if(any(x)) {
                            toString(names(which(x))) 
                          }
                       else NA
                    })
```

Or another option would to get the `row/column` index with `which` by specifying the `arr.ind=TRUE`.  Grouped by the `row` of 'indx' (`indx[,1]`), we `paste` the column names of 'df' ('val').  If there are some rows missing i.e. without any 'Yes' element, then use `ifelse` to create `NA` for the missing row.

```
 indx <- which(df=='Yes', arr.ind=TRUE)
 val <- tapply(names(df)[indx[,2]], indx[,1], FUN=toString)
 df$Expected_Result <- ifelse(seq_len(nrow(df)) %in% names(val), val, NA)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No"), c2 = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No"), c3 = c("Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), c4 = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No")), .Names = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"),
class =    "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Your `tapply` example was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
colnames(df) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

test <- (apply(df,1,function(x) which(x=="Yes")))

df$cols <- lapply(test,names)
```

This was along the lines of what you were initially trying I think.

To tidy the output you could:

```
 df$cols <- gsub("c(", "", df$cols, fixed = TRUE)

 df$cols <- gsub(")", "", df$cols, fixed = TRUE)
```

This removes the `c()`.

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to convert the resulting vector results in the df$cols to string or character? Perhaps using toString?

Comment: Awesome. I also removed extra quotes with: df$cols <- gsub("\"", "", df$cols, fixed = TRUE)

Comment: @ramesh, Its great that youhad so many answers to your question. If they worked out you could accept one.